# where is the best place to adjust how ember-data talks to sails

Tags: ember-data, sails.js, ember-cli

I am trying to implement an ember-cli (ember-data) to sails.js connection.  I have installed **ember-data-sails** and have a simple model and am using the socketAdapter...

**adapters/application.js**

```
import SailsSocketAdapter from 'ember-data-sails/adapters/sails-socket';

export default SailsSocketAdapter.extend({
  useCSRF:              true,
  coalesceFindRequests: true,
  namespace:            'api/v1',
  //defaultSerializer: '-rest',
});
```

Example Model:

**RequestType.js**

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name : { type: 'string' },
    desc : { type: 'string' },
    requestSubType : { type: 'hasMany' }
  }
};
```

So far it is mostly working, I can get a list of RequestTypes ok.  However if i try and nest a route to display/create the **hasMany** relationship, then i have an issue.

**request-sub-types/new/routes.js**
This file, requests the **Parent** model **requestType** first, and then creates a new record, inserting the Parent in the **belongsTo** attribute.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var requestType = this.modelFor('requestTypes/view');
        return requestType.get('requestSubTypes').createRecord({
            requestType: requestType
        });
    }
});
```

**request-types/view/route.js**
This file is the model I think that is being requested above.  The issue here is the params object that get fed through is:

```
{ requestType_id: 6 }
```

but if this is passed to the store.query call then nothing gets returned.  If however I change the params object to:

```
{ id: 6 }
```

then I do see a record come back from the sails api.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        console.log('RT: View Route MODEL', params);
        var query = {};
        if(params.requestType_id) {
            query.id= params.requestType_id;
        }
        return this.store.query('requestType', query);
    }
});
```

So My question is what do i need to edit to make the Primary Key definitions match up. so that Ember-data and Sails can talk to each other correctly?  Is it in a serializer somewhere, the Sails API or in each model call?

thanks... and sorry if the above doesn't make any sense! :)